# Compiling a "portable version" binary of a program

Tags: debian, compiling, dependencies

For lots of open source software, the compiling and installation step is usually `./configure`, `make & make install`. However in this process configure may locate dependencies in the system, and make links to them. This makes the binary unusable for direct portable distribution.

My question is, what is the standard building pipeline on linux to build a portable version of those programs (that automatically bundles the dependencies)?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about building and packaging software for Debian or Linux in general?

Comment: That's called static linking. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20068947/1032785

Comment: Other more modern options for that distribution is via snaps or flatpaks

Comment: @kemotep my priority is to make these things work on a Debian system, but it would be better if some solution generalizes to all distributions.